# Why Firebug is displaying old log?

Tags: firefox, firebug

My Firefox (8.0.1) and Firebug (1.8.4) are displaying old log everytime I visit website?

*(clearing console works once but after refreshing log is there again)*

[image: Firebug displaying old logs]

Any help? Any suggestions? Or maybe you could tell me where I set it so it is displayed on every page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT mantra: reboot / reinstall.